# Django - Checking for two models if their primary keys match

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models (`sett`, `data_parsed`), and `data_parsed` have a foreign key to `sett`.

```
class sett(models.Model):
    setid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    block = models.ForeignKey(mapt, related_name='sett_block')
    username = models.ForeignKey(mapt, related_name='sett_username')
    ts = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.setid)

class data_parsed(models.Model):
    setid = models.ForeignKey(sett, related_name='data_parsed_setid', primary_key=True)
    block = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    time = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.setid)
```

The `data_parsed` model should have the same amount of rows, but there is a possibility that they are not in "sync".

To avoid this from happening. I basically do these two steps:

1. Check if `sett.objects.all().count()` == `data_parsed.objects.all().count()`

   This works great for a fast check, and it takes literally seconds in 1 million rows.
2. If they are not the same, I would check for all the `sett` model's pk, exclude the ones already found in `data_parsed`.

   ```
   sett.objects.select_related().exclude(
   setid__in = data_parsed.objects.all().values_list('setid', flat=True)).iterator():
   ```

   Basically what this does is select all the objects in sett that exclude all the setid already in data_parsed. This method "works", but it will take around 4 hours for 1 million rows.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: How about adding a created/updated timestamp, and see what has changed since the last check ?

Comment: Something like `SELECT s FROM sett s WHERE s.setid NOT IN (SELECT d.setid FROM data_parsed d);`? Is there a way to do custom queries in your ORM?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm trying not to add anymore extra data to the models. Plus I'm also trying to avoid using custom queries at the moment.

Comment: About the created/update time stamp, if the amount of rows that was added between time stamps was ~1 million, then the time it would take is still 4 hours. Doesn't look like a long term solution though?

Comment: If sett and data_parsed must have same amount of rows, how about one to one relationship? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

Comment: so, as per answer, to find sett objects without data_parsed relation you can simply filter sett objects with "backref"=None.

Comment: You mean sett.objects.filter("backref"=None)? Is there a documentation where I can have a look? Thanks

Comment: Or did you mean filter(data_parsed_setid=None)?

Comment: Yea, thats what I meant, and the answer from Todor is even better.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I've tried both solutions and they work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding setts without data_parsed using the reverse relation:

```
setts.objects.filter(data_parsed_setid__isnull=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If i am getting it right you are trying to keep a list of processed objects in another model by setting a foreign key.

You have only one data_parsed object by every sett object, so a many to one relationship is not needed. You could use [one to one relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) and then check which object has that field as empty.

With a foreign key you could try to filter using the reverse query but that is at object level so i doubt that works.